# Continuous square root function on $\mathbb C^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

There is another thread about this topic but I'm interested if the following reasoning is correct:

Let $f:\mathbb C^*\to\mathbb C^*$ be a continuous function that satisfies $f^2(z)=z$. We know that there is a holomorphic square root $g(z)=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\log(z))$ on the slit plane $\mathbb C^-$. Now we can observer that $$\frac{f^2(z)}{g^2(z)}=\frac{z}{z}=1$$ and thus $f^2=g^2$, so either $f=g$ or $f=-g$. The case $f=g$ can't happen because then $g$ could be continuously extended on $\mathbb C^*$ which we know isn't possible. And the case $f=-g$ would mean that $-g$ could be continously extended and therefor $g$ as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That proof is incomplete. You did not justify that$$f^2=g^2\implies f=g\vee f=-g.$$Of course, for each individual $z$ it is true that $f(z)=g(z)$ or $f(z)=-g(z)$, but this is not enough to deduce that $f=g$ or $f=-g$.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the fact that a 'constant of integration' is in fact any piece-wise constant function.

Comment: How could this be repaired?

Comment: By learning about Riemann surfaces as they were introduced precisely to deal with this type of situation

Comment: Well, I don't know anything at all about Riemann surfaces. Isn't there some sort of elementary way?

Comment: @RedLantern This can be repaired observing that $\frac fg$ is a continuous funtions which takes only two values: $1$ and $-1$. Therefore, either it is always equal to $1$ or it is always equal to $-1$.

Comment: @Conrad I disagree. Please read my previous comment.

Comment: my point is that there is no such function on $\mathbb(C^{*})$, but you need a Riemann surface (a careful glueing of two copies of the plane minus the cut rays) to define it as you need to twist the half line you cut to determine the logarithm (or branch of square root) so the below in one copy corresponds to above in the other copy say if you cut on the negative reals; in particular all comments regarding such are moot as they argue about the empty set

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos As I see it I just need to add your comment in between and then my proof should be done? Because either $f=g$ or $f=-g$ can't hold for the stated reasons?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks again then! You're really helpful with all my complex analysis questions.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.